# How to get real minuses in typewriter font

Tags: fonts, typewriter

In many fonts the minus signs `-` have been shrunken to hyphens in the last decades which looks quite odd in the context of programming languages. How can I get back the original size which is exactly as wide as the plus sign `+`?

I am using

```
     \usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      \usepackage{microtype}
```

As an example, consider:

```
\begin{verbatim}
]+[
]-[
\end{verbatim}
```

Edit: Thanks for all answers, but I have still some issues here, mostly:

When copying text from the produced pdf, the minuses (or minī) do not have the character code of `-` but rather another one (x2212).

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "minus signs... have shrunken to hyphens." That's dependent on people's use. If you're using it in a math context, use math, as in `$a - b$`. If you're talking about the symbol, in text, you can consider `\textminus`, if that's available or define it in that way.

Comment: And in the context of `\verb` or `verbatim`?

Comment: `\verb` or `verbatim` are used to set things they are typed, and for that a dash `-` is used for both contexts (hyphens or minus), so I wouldn't think it would make a difference there. Perhaps that's just a personal opinion.

Answer (score 10):

It's possibly a bad design choice of Bera Mono, surely not something that's found in general monospaced fonts.

The font has a longer hyphen in the TS1 encoding, which can be obtained as `\textminus` and it's possible to hack `verbatim` into producing `\textminus` instead of the short hyphen.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\make@hyphen@textminus}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`-\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{{\usefont{TS1}{fvm}{m}{n}\textminus}}%
}
\AddToHook{cmd/verbatim@nolig@list/after}{\make@hyphen@textminus}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\verb|-+|

\begin{verbatim}
]+[
]-[
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

First message: when you use the symbol `-` from a typically configured keyboard, then it means the hyphen character, no minus. The hyphen character is much shorter than minus. Classical TeX prints minus when the hyphen character is in the math mode, i.e. `$-$`.

Fonts designed to emulate typewriter should have the hyphen character equal to minus, because it wasn't differ in old typewriters and because it is used for programming code, where no hyphen character is (only minus).

You are using Bera Mono font which doesn't meet this feature: it includes both, hyphen character and minus. But only hyphen character is mapped in T1 encoding you are using. More implementation details follow.

I know Bera Mono font only in old PostScript `*.pfb` format (no Unicode font). It is installed in TeXlive as `fvmr8a.pfb`. This font includes real minus character at the slot 173 (0xad). Unfortunately, `vf` file which implements the `8t` encoding (T1 encoding) doesn't support this character. You can use `raw` tfm `fvwr8r` where the minus is encoded at slot 12:

```
\font\f=fvmr8r

\def\ttfont{\f\lccode`~=`- \lowercase{\def~}{\char12 }\catcode`-=13 }

test fvmr8r: {\ttfont text in +- type-writer }

\bye
```

or you can use directly PostScript font `fvmr8a` where the minus is encoded at slot 173:

```
\pdfmapline{=fvmr8a BeraSansMono-Roman <fvmr8a.pfb}
\font\f=fvmr8a

\def\ttfont{\f\lccode`~=`- \lowercase{\def~}{\char173 }\catcode`-=13 }

test fvmr8a: {\ttfont text in +- type-writer }

\bye
```

If the font was implemented as a Unicode font life would be easier.

As egreg mentioned there is another encoding in a jungle of 8-bit encodings named TS1 (or `8c` in tfm file names). The minus has slot 61 in this encoding:)

```
\font\f=fvmr8t
\font\fc=fvmr8c

\def\ttfont{\f\lccode`~=`- \lowercase{\def~}{{\fc\char61}}\catcode`-=13 }

test fvmr8c: {\ttfont text in +- type-writer }

\bye
```

This last solution must to repeatedly change the current font to another font only to get the minus character because TS1 encoding doesn't include normal letters and normal ASCII characters.

Comment: nice - hunting;-)

Comment: Since typewriters were basically designed to produce text, I think it's pretty unlikely the character was intended to represent minus as opposed to hyphen. The most common usage was surely as a hyphen.  Whether the hyphen looked more like some particular font's hyphen or more like its minus I don't know. Possibly it depended on the particular typewriter. I somewhat doubt it looked like minus, because that would have looked very odd in text. But I haven't (yet?) checked.

Comment: If the typewriter provided the plus symbol https://i.pinimg.com/originals/77/99/7d/77997d62220ee7d2ff108bde4acebad8.jpg then the hyphen symbol has had compatible shape to the plus and it was used in both cases: as hyphen or as minus. But many typewriters didn't provide plus, no symbol 1 (replaced by l), no symbol zero etc. Then hyphen was hyphen. Like this https://c1.staticflickr.com/7/6220/6306407308_461599ce78_b.jpg

Answer (score 5):

In math mode, the hyphen `-` is by default converted to a minus sign. That  is, `$-$` will be `−` in the PDF.

In normal text mode, you can use `−` (U+2212) directly using xelatex or lualatex, as well as  `\textminus` with any compiler to have also a true minus sign.

In verbatim mode U+2212 is equal to the hyphen by default, but many fonts allow to use a different character, so is "only" matter of select a good font.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent0pt\parskip0pt
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\begin{document}\obeylines
+ - is a hyphen 
+ − is U+2212 
$+$ $-$ is a minus sign
+ \textminus{} is \verb|\texminus|
\begin{verbatim}
+ - is a hyphen 
+ − is U+2212 
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```